# OCaml Understanding Functions and Partial Applications

Tags: functional-programming, ocaml

I am writing a form of form of transform in OCaml that takes in a function and also accepts a list to transform.  I understand something is wrong with my pattern matching in terms of type-checking, as it will not compile and claims the types do not match but I am not sure what exactly is wrong with my cases.
I receive an actual declaration error underlining the name of the function when I attempt to compile.

```
 let rec convert (fun: 'b -> 'c option) (l: 'b list) : 'c list =
 begin match l with
| [] -> []
| h::tl -> if f h = Some h then h :: convert f tl
         else convert f tl

end
```

I wrote the following test, which should pass in order to ensure the function works properly.

```
let test () : bool =
let f = func x -> if x > 3 then Some (x + 1) else None in
convert f [-1; 3; 4] = [5]
;; run_test "Add one" test
```

I am pretty confident the error is somewhere in my second pattern match.

Comment: Note that as of OCaml 4.08 this is available in the standard library as [`List.filter_map`](https://v2.ocaml.org/api/List.html#VALfilter_map).

Answer (score 2):

1. You should provide the exact error message in the future when asking about a compilation error (as well as the position the compiler complains about).
2. In `h :: convert f tl`, `convert f tl` is `'c list`, but `h` is `'b`, so you can't combine them like this. Neither does `f h = Some h` make sense: `f h` is `'c option` and `Some h` is `'b option`. You probably want to match `f h` instead:

   ```
   | h::tl -> match f h with
                | Some h1 -> ...
                | None -> ...
   ```

Comment: 1. Will do, thank you for the suggestion. This error underlines the name of the function, convert, in the first line.  2. When you say match f h, do you mean replace the pattern match with h::tl? Or the match with the 'b list, l, in the second line of the function? Thank you.

Comment: 1. You should see the error message as well, as shown here: https://ocaml.org/learn/tutorials/common_error_messages.html. If you don't, this needs to be fixed first, because the error messages are very useful. 2. I've extended the answer (incompletely, because it's better if you try to finish it).